# The number of samples in the render view does not go up

Tags: render-layers

I don't speak English, so I use a translation tool!
The number of samples doesn't go up in the viewport render view, but somehow the number of samples goes up when the blender is minimized!
Is there a way to increase the sample size without minimizing it?

After editing.
At first time i open render of viewport,  it dose not work properly. but once when i minimize the window that number is going up properly,  What i want to know is the way not to minimize?? 
[image][image]

Comment: That's a challenge. sample size goes up, meaning Blender keeps rendering? What language to you speak, maybe someone can help clarify.

Comment: Hi, welcome, images may help, edit your question and add a screenshot showing how you are comparing those numbers...

Comment: As I can see you have a volumetric which takes alot of time to render so when you minimize it is still rendering and the sampled number increases .You can increase rendering in the viewport by decreasing the size of the viewport or using your GPU if you have one.